# If 1 is a specific date, how can I convert back and forth between date and integer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, date

I've seen varying discussions on here on converting between different date formats; what I'm curious on how to do in VB.Net is convert between integer and date and back again.

So for example, if 1 is 01/10/1990 and 9 is 09/10/1990; how would I convert back and forth on wider ranges in VB.Net?

My example dates are purely hypothetical, realistically it will be say 1 is 1/10/1984, whereas 1990 may have a 365.25 *6 increase.

Thanks for all your input thus far

Resolved

Comment: Start with September 30th 1990 and add N days? (And in reverse, subtract September 30th to get a Timespan, and take TotalDays from that...) I'm not sure whether that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Crackhouse2, we hope that your issue has been resolved. May I suggest some further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... regards...

Comment: @Monty thanks for the further reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
    Dim date1 As New Date(1990, 10, 01)

    Dim newDate = date1.AddDays(1000)

    Dim dateInterval = newDate.Subtract(date1).TotalDays
```

'newDate' is now 1000 days after 1990, 10, 01

and

'dateInterval' should = 1000 days

Hope that helps....

Answer (score 0):

Does the integer that you are using matter?  If not, just use Ticks:

```
// Convert current date/time to ticks
Dim n As Long = Now.Ticks

// Make ticks into new Date/time
Dim d As Date = New Date(n)
```

Comment: The OP appears to want consecutive integers to represent consecutive days (1 = 1/10/1990, 9 = 9/10/1990). This code doesn't do that.

Comment: Exactly, so basically any integer above or below 1 will span out in an equal number of days, so 14 would be 2 weeks from point 1, -14 would be 2 weeks prior and so forth